# Finding a string in a file [C]

Tags: c

Could anyone tell me the way how to find string (which you enter in a program) in a `.txt` file without using function for that?(Just need an algorithm for that nothing else) EXAMPLE: i have file named `NAMES.txt` with surnames on the first line separate with space like that:

`John Peter Paul`

and in my program I enter name for example `Paul` and it finds it in that file and write `"the name is there"`

`name = Paul;`

I have one method on my mind that if i enter for example Paul to my program it would scan all chars one by one in that file in a row and if `name[1] = P` then it would start scaning and comparing letters and if they were the same it would each time increase counter `p` by one `(p++)` and if `p = lenghth` of name then the name would be there (there might be 1 bug which comes to my mind that if you enter `Paul` and in the file theres name Paula it will actually write `"The name is there"` if i used that method but it should not be impossible to debug)

Could anyone also tell me if my written method is possible to realize ?

Comment: Yes, your written method is possible to realise.  Have you actually tried to code your algorithm yet?  If no, I suggest you give it a go and if you get stuck, ask us about it.  If yes, tell us how far you got and where you are stuck and we should be able to help you.

Comment: yes i will try to do it but as somebody below mentioned i think its just uneffective.

Comment: @JeremyP  im trying to code it right now but i need to find some command which will assign a char from file on given position to variable. Like for example in my file there are names Paul Peter and from that file i want to assignt char "t" to variable c , something like c = fgetc[7] so c will store char "t" but fgetc doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest avoiding reading the entire file into memory. Large files might result in large memory consumption, which is far from ideal.

Presumably you have the string to search for in memory somewhere; it's already in an allocation. Create another allocation of the size of that string, and read that many bytes into it... Don't forget to account for the `'\0'` string terminator.

Check to see if it matches. If the string matches, well, obviously you've found a match within that file. If it doesn't, shift the array one byte left, read another byte onto the end of it. Rinse, lather, repeat until you find a match.

---

The bug you mentioned implies that you need a string terminator, in the file, somewhere. Technically speaking, a string terminator is a `'\0'`, but you could substitute any terminal value(s). Just replace the value(s) you choose (perhaps whitespace?) with a `'\0'` as you're reading.

Answer (score 0):

Function [`fgets()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) will be useful for this task as you can store whole string in buffer instead of one character at a time .

```
 fgets(name,100,fp)
```

Where `name` is string pointer where string read is stored ,`100` is the number of characters to be read and `fp` is the FILE pointer from where you want to read.

And then you can use function `strcmp()` to compare the string and `name  you want to search` .So it will eliminate the other possibility of matching with a different name.

Comment: What happens if `"Pa"` occurs at `name + 97`, and `"ul"` occurs at the beginning of the next read? Technically, `"Paul"` occurs in the file, but your (partial) method won't identify it.

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor  Yes but that's what he don't want I think so as he explained with example of `Paula`. So according to what you say sir every word will be found in a particularly big file.